# Submitting a form logs the user out

Tags: forms, symfony, form-submit, symfony4

I'm currently running into a very confusing problem with Symfony 4 (or not even that, I don't know). I've set up a login/registration system manually, which has been working great, up until now. I've developed a form where one can create branches for their main company. I used a **FormType** for that exact manner:

```
<?php

// src/Form/UserType.php
namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Filiale;
use App\Entity\Kammer;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

class FilialType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('apothekenname', TextType::class)
            ->add('email', EmailType::class)
            ->add('anrede', TextType::class)
            ->add('titel', TextType::class, array(
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('vorname', TextType::class)
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('adresszusatz', TextType::class, array(
                'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('strasse', TextType::class)
            ->add('hausnummer', TextType::class)
            ->add('plz', NumberType::class)
            ->add('ort', TextType::class)
            //->add('kammer', TextType::class)
            ->add('kammer', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => Kammer::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Filiale::class,
        ));
    }
}

?>
```

The **view** rendering the FormType looks like this, where there's a separate button triggering the Bootstrap modal dialog:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-add-filiale" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Neue Filialapotheke anlegen</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Schließen">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        {{ form_start(form_add_filiale) }}
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xl-3" for="filiale-apothekenname">Apothekenname</label>
                <div class="col-xl-9">
                    {{ form_widget(form_add_filiale.apothekenname) }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xl-3" for="filiale-anrede">Anrede</label>
                <div class="col-xl-9">
                    {{ form_widget(form_add_filiale.anrede) }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xl-3" for="filiale-titel">Titel</label>
                <div class="col-xl-9">
                    {{ form_widget(form_add_filiale.titel) }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xl-3" for="filiale-vorname">Vorname</label>
                <div class="col-xl-9">
                    {{ form_widget(form_add_filiale.vorname) }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xl-3" for="filiale-name">Name</label>
                <div class="col-xl-9">
                    {{ form_widget(form_add_filiale.name) }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xl-3" for="filiale-strasse">Straße</label>
                <div class="col-xl-9">
                    {{ form_widget(form_add_filiale.strasse) }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xl-3" for="filiale-hausnummer">Hausnummer</label>
                <div class="col-xl-9">
                    {{ form_widget(form_add_filiale.hausnummer) }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xl-3" for="filiale-adresszusatz">Adresszusatz</label>
                <div class="col-xl-9">
                    {{ form_widget(form_add_filiale.adresszusatz) }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xl-3" for="filiale-plz">PLZ</label>
                <div class="col-xl-9">
                    {{ form_widget(form_add_filiale.plz) }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xl-3" for="filiale-stadt">Stadt</label>
                <div class="col-xl-9">
                    {{ form_widget(form_add_filiale.ort) }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xl-3" for="filiale-email">Email</label>
                <div class="col-xl-9">
                    {{ form_widget(form_add_filiale.email) }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-xl-3" for="filiale-kammerbezirk">Kammerbezirk</label>
                <div class="col-xl-9">
                    {{ form_widget(form_add_filiale.kammer) }}
                </div>
            </div>

            <button type="submit">Hu</button>
        {{ form_end(form_add_filiale) }}
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Abbrechen</button>
        <button id="modal-add-filiale-save" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Speichern</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The **Controller function** processing the form, renderung and submission looks like this:

```
public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authUtils, AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authChecker) {
        $isLoggedIn = ($authChecker->isGranted('ROLE_USER') || $authChecker->isGranted('ROLE_USER_MO'));

        if($isLoggedIn) {
            $filiale = new Filiale();
            $form = $this->createForm(FilialType::class, $filiale);

            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $filiale->setUser($this->getUser());

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($filiale);
                $em->flush();

                return $this->render('default/startpage_loggedin.html.twig', array(
                'breadcrumb' => 'BROTKRUMEN',
                'form_add_filiale' => $form->createView(),
                'toast_finished' => 1,
            ));
            }

            return $this->render('default/startpage_loggedin.html.twig', array(
                'breadcrumb' => 'BROTKRUMEN',
                'form_add_filiale' => $form->createView(),
            ));
        }
        else {
            // get the login error if there is one
            $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

            // last username entered by the user
            $lastUsername = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

            return $this->render('default/startpage_loggedout.html.twig', array(
                'last_username' => $lastUsername,
                'error'         => $error,
            ));
        }
    }
```

While the code isn't perfectly arranged and I'm probably missing some best practices, I still find the problem I'm facing weird. The form is only accessible while logged in - when I click the button to open the modal, then fill the form out and then press the submit button, I'm automatically getting logged out and the error message "invalid credentials" is displayed.

However, when I'm outsourcing the form rendering and form handling to a new view and a new controller function, the code does exactly what it's supposed to do, without touching the logged in user.

I'm basically running out of ideas and would appreciate any hint you guys could offer. Thank you in advance!

Edit: Security.yml

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
        legacy_encoder:
            algorithm: md5
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations: 1

    providers:
        in_memory: { memory: ~ }
        db_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            #pattern: ^/
            #http_basic: ~

            anonymous: ~
            provider: db_provider

            user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker

            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /

            form_login:
                login_path: home
                check_path: home

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/motivwelten, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/services/.*, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/shop, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/shop/.*, roles: ROLE_USER }

    erase_credentials: false
```

Comment: can you show your security.yml ?

Comment: @MichałG I've edited the Security.yml in the original post. Might the problem be that I'm basically submitting to the login_path route without passing credentials, so symfony tries verifying that "user" and fails?

Comment: Your action named is `login`. What is its routing?

Comment: home:
    path: /
    defaults: 
        _controller: 'App\Controller\SecurityController::login'

Answer (score 0):

While not a direct solution to the initial question I asked, I fixed the problem by moving every logic but the login away from the login method in my controller.

This should probably be the better practice anyways. I believe submitting to the /login route tirggers a login event and, as there are no credentials, the service can't verify the user and terminates the session while displaying "invalid credentials" as well.